# How can I easily use a damaged hose bibb outlet?

Tags: plumbing, repair

The threads on my hose bibb outlet are damaged and in pretty bad shape. I have not done my own plumbing work before and am wondering if there is some type of solution that would not require opening up the siding to replace the entire bibb. I'm hoping for a solution outside the box possibly so I don't need to hire a plumber although I will if necessary. As is, leaking at the connection is pretty bad if I try to use the outlet.

[image: my beat up bibb]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about if you used a screw-on hose bib anti-siphon adapter. You could screw/jam it on along with a generous amount of 2-part epoxy putty (like J.B. Weld) and have new garden hose threads... and anti-siphon protection as a bonus!

[image]

Comment: I'd like to report back that after using this method for the past 3 months, it was completely successful. I just have to watch out for the splash of water at the end now :) Thanks Jimmy!